# Make Byobu open new screens in home directory

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, byobu

I don't know if this is something that's changed in a recent version of byobu, but now when I create a new screen, the new screen is in the same directory as my current window. At first this wasn't too annoying, a simple "cd ~" would get me where I wanted. But I've been noticing strange things. During a gem install, if I create a new window, I end up inside the directory that the gem is being installed to ( when using rbenv ).

I just want this to stop. How do I set up byobu/tmux so that it opens all new windows in my home directory?

I've looked through a few files, but I can't seem to see any commands ( such as errant 'chdir' ) that would be causing this.

Comment: By the way, "cd" is enough to get you to your home directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ubuntu, I can get the desired behavior by adding the following line to ${HOME}/.byobu/.tmuxrc :

```
set-option -g default-path $HOME
```

This option is document in tmux's manual page:

> ```
> set-option [-agoqsuw] [-t target-session | target-window] option value
>               (alias: set)
>         Set a window option with -w (equivalent to the set-window-option
>         command), a server option with -s, otherwise a session option.
>
>         If -g is specified, the global session or window option is set.
>         With -a, and if the option expects a string, value is appended
>         to the existing setting.  The -u flag unsets an option, so a session
>         inherits the option from the global options.  It is not possible to
>         unset a global option.
>
>         The -o flag prevents setting an option that is already set.
>
>         The -q flag suppresses the informational message (as if the quiet
>         server option was set).
>
>         Available window options are listed under set-window-option.
>
>         value depends on the option and may be a number, a string, or a flag
>         (on, off, or omitted to toggle).
>
>         Available server options are:
>
>         <snip>
>
>         default-path path
>
>         Set the default working directory for new panes.  If empty (the
>         default), the working directory is determined from the process running
>         in the active pane, from the command line environment or from the
>         working directory where the session was created.  Otherwise the same
>         options are available as for the -c flag to new-window.
> ```

I initially tried with `set-option -g default-path ~`, but it appears that tmux doesn't understand that alias.

Update: the above doesn't work with byobu 5.92 (maybe other versions) and tmux 1.9, as tmux has removed the `default-path` option. It seems the byobu dev was using that to get the behavior where new windows open in the CWD, whereas I and the questioner wanted it to open in the HOME dir by default. In the new default bindings in `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux` I found this:

```
bind-key -n F2 new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" \; rename-window "-"
bind-key -n C-F2 display-panes \; split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind-key -n S-F2 display-panes \; split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

To get the desired behavior of always making byobu open new screens in your home directory, add the following to `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux`:

```
bind-key -n F2 new-window -c "$HOME" \; rename-window "-"
bind-key -n C-F2 display-panes \; split-window -h -c "$HOME"
bind-key -n S-F2 display-panes \; split-window -v -c "$HOME"
```

Comment: For laziness sake, you can remove either the `-c "#{pane_current_path}"` or `-c "$HOME"` sections of each line and it'll default to `$HOME`.

Comment: If, like me, you're using GNU Screen bindings (C-a), base your bindings on `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/tmux-screen-keys.conf`. In other words, put `bind ^C new-window`, `bind c new-window` and `bind | split-window` in `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux`.